# Ошибка в плагине AudioPlayer js

Tags: javascript, html, аудио, плагин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подключил плагин для стилизации аудиоплеера, все работает, но выдает ошибки, иногда их может быть больше, а иногда меньше, как их исправить?

```
    <div class="audio">
        <audio preload="auto" controls><source src="audio/audio.mp3"></audio>
            <script src="js/audioplayer.js"></script>
            <script>$( function() { $( 'audio' ).audioPlayer(); } );</script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        (function(doc){var addEvent='addEventListener',type='gesturestart',qsa='querySelectorAll',scales=[1,1],meta=qsa in doc?doc[qsa]('meta[name=viewport]'):[];function fix(){meta.content='width=device-width,minimum-scale='+scales[0]+',maximum-scale='+scales[1];doc.removeEventListener(type,fix,true);}if((meta=meta[meta.length-1])&&addEvent in doc){fix();scales=[.25,1.6];doc[addEvent](type,fix,true);}}(document));
$( function() { $( 'audio' ).audioPlayer(); } );
    </script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код плагина: https://jsfiddle.net/ucrutva5/

Comment: Если это не самописный `plugin`, добавьте линк на `source code`.

Comment: я надеюсь я правильно вас понял и добавил в вопрос то, что нужно)

Comment: Ну, из сообщения об ошибке же видно, что в "плагине" баг (выход за границы массива при вызове TimeRanges.end)

Comment: а возможно как-то это пофиксить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отредактируйте метод `updateLoadBar`(строка 101) так

```
updateLoadBar = setInterval( function()
    {
        if (theAudio.onprogress) {
            barLoaded.width( ( theAudio.buffered.end( 0 ) / theAudio.duration ) * 100 + '%' );
            if( theAudio.buffered.end( 0 ) >= theAudio.duration )
                clearInterval( updateLoadBar );
        }
    }, 100 );
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651719/why-does-audio-buffered-end0-get-an-error-message-when-i-try-to-get-buffered-t

Comment: Спасибо большое, после долгих мучений помогли мне

Answer (score 1):

1. `Строка 106 в jsfiddle` -

   barLoaded.width( ( theAudio.buffered.end( 0 ) / theAudio.duration ) * 100 + '%' );

Дело в том что ,Вы, вызываете метод end(как я понимаю метод библиотеки jQuery), на элементе, в котором пусто, необходимо обработать ошибку через if или ещё как нибудь.
У объекта theAudio свойство duration имеет значение NaN, а значит на выходе при выполнении данного выражение получаете NaN.
2. Вам не даёт нормальной отладки setInterval который выполняет данный код каждую милисекунду (100) - что очень быстро, и консоль забивается постоянными вызовами той же самой ошибкой, желательно хотя бы его убрать для отладки.
3. Хочу сказать что свойство duration  так и будет выдавать ошибку в коде и дальше так как имеет значение NaN - любая арифметическая операция с NaN даёт NaN.

Данную ошибку удалось избежать вот ссылка
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucrutva5/13/)

Comment: Начало код со 101 строки, и увеличил setInterval, можете вернуть в исходное состояние, ошибки не возникнет.